# Increase search speed on 30 tables

Tags: sql-server, performance

I want to do a search on 30 tables
I'm queried like this:

```
select count(*)
from view1
where field1 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field1 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field1 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field1 like N'%searchKeyword%' or ...
union all
select count(*)
from view2
where field11 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field12 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field13 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field14 like N'%searchKeyword%' or ...
union all
select count(*)
from view3
where field21 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field22 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field23 like N'%searchKeyword%' or field24 like N'%searchKeyword%' or ...
union all
.
.
.
```

In this method, due to the large number of fields in the tables, when the number of datas increases, the speed of the pitch decreases

What is your offer

Comment: Using a wildcard like `%searchkeyword%` is a horrible, horrible idea. Let alone doing it umpteen times. Get rid of that first `%` if you can and let SQL use indices. And if you can't get rid of it, consider using Full Text Search (FTS). Think of it this way: what if I hand you a phonebook and ask you to find me all `Richards%` (e.g. `searchkeyword%` matching `Richards`, `Richardson` etc.). Now I hand you the same phonebook and ask you to find me all `%son` (e.g. `%searchkeyword%`, matching 'Johnson', 'Wilson', 'Jackson' etc). What would take _you_ longest?

Comment: Plus anyone that has `'son'` in the middle of their name (not just the end), so a double barrel name like `'Hudson-Lloyd'` or a name like `'Parsons'`, would also be a candidate.

Comment: @RobIII: I have read about full text search.But my problem is that I'm doing the search on the view and the viewes have 9-10 left and right outer joins that FTS they do not support